# Where does Google Drive File Stream store offline files and folders on a Mac?

Tags: backup, data-synchronization, google-apps

I use Google Drive File Stream for work, and there are certain mission-critical files that I need available for offline access.  File Stream makes this easy: control-click on the file, and choose "Available Offline".  Great!

But where are these files *stored*?  With the "old" Google Drive (now "Backup & Sync") there was a Google Drive folder at the top of my user directory; this folder was always available, whether Backup & Sync was running or not, and Time Machine would back it up for me (if I wanted it to).  With File Stream, I have no idea where those files are -- when the program is not running the "Google Drive" volume unmounts from my system, and the files appear to be completely inaccessible; moreover I don't think Time Machine backs them up.

Where is File Stream storing these offline files?  Is there a way to back them up, or to access them when the program is not running?

Just for clarity’s sake: I am interested in the answers to these questions on MacOS, specifically in Catalina, if that makes a difference.

Comment: As this is not *explicitly* about Google Drive File Stream on **macOS** you run the risk of having it marked as off-topic. You may want to consider making it more explicitly about this service on macOS.

Comment: @SteveChambers how about that edit at the end?

Comment: Better but unsure. You may want to ask this on a Google discussion group, they might be better equipped to answer that question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Google Drive for desktop (formerly known as Google Drive File Stream) stores cached files in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/DriveFS/$account_id/content_cache`, where $account_id is the numeric ID of your google account. The files aren't encrypted or anything, but they don't have any metadata (or even their original filenames) so I don't think you'll find them terribly useful. The metadata seems to be stored in various SQLite databases in in the `$account_id` folder. In an emergency an expert might be able to reconstruct the original file names and folder structure.

If you want a full backup of your Google Drive, you can try backing up the Google Drive volume itself (`/Volumes/GoogleDrive`), while Google Drive for desktop is running.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH
I had transferred film data to offline-available google folder, it copied to computer in 40 seconds ( 4G) and I let it sync it to cloud for night. On morning there was "Error in syncing" and the clip was not found on desktop, google drive, various folders, even find . and mlocate couldn't find it. But there it was, in Lost-n-Found dir.

Comment: Same! Thanks for sharing about the lost_and_found folder

Answer (score 3):

Since MacOS 13 (or possibly an update of the Google Drive software) they are stored in

```
~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-[username]/My\ Drive/
```

using their regular name. In fact, it is not just offline files that are stored there, it looks like it is a mirror of the whole file structure but the files are empty until you access them.